# Generating The Keys of a Dictionary Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I ask the user to input how many values they are willing to assign to the list values and then they start assigning values to the list values

```
list_length = int(input("How much values are you going to enter?: "))
values = []
for x in range (list_length):
    values.append(input("Enter a new value: "))

print(values)
```

I want to generate a keys list `keys = []` where based on the input of list_length the keys list will contain `keys = ['key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3',...]` so that I can finally do something like `dict = dict(zip(keys,values))`

Comment: `keys = ["key_{}".format(i+1) for i in range(0,len(values))]`

Comment: Jean-Francois Fabre, can you please make this comment an answer so that i tick it

Comment: well, Ignacio's answer is more complete: it build the keys _and_ the dict at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too much work.

```
D = {'key_{}'.format(i): v for (i, v) in enumerate(values, start=1)}
```

Comment: For 3.6+: `{f'key_{i}': v for i, v in enumerate(values, 1)}`.

Answer (score 0):

To get key listing:

```
keys = ["key_{}".format(i+1) for i in range(list_length)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
keys = ["key_{}".format(i+1) for i in range(list_length)]
```

This seems to be the simplest solution.